# Trimming and sorting two array

Tags: c#, arrays, double, contain

I have two arrays one is double array ,has the scores of words and other one is string array has the words.Like this

```
scores={23.25 ,5.2  , 1.5 , 13.00}
words={car, bag, cars, phone}
```

I would like to sum up values of car and cars and delete cars from words and its value from scores array and get these two arrays

```
scores={24.75 , 5.2 ,13.00 }
words={car, bag, phone}
```

Then scores array is going to be sorted that I can get TOP 2 words car and phone and pass them to textbox2

```
for (i=0;i<words.Length;i++){
for (j=i+1;j<words.Length;j++){
if (words.Contains(words[j])){
     delete words[j]//here i need help
      scores[i]+= scores[i]+scores[j]
}
}

Array.Sort(scores); //and here after sorting how can i get corresponding top 2 words
```

Comment: How do you determine that "car" and "cars" are the same thing, but not, say, "card"?

Comment: And why didn't you use a Dictionary when you have key-value pairs?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I didnt think about it,nice point

Comment: @FrodeF. I dont know how to use it